# How to send only the ClientHello TLS 1.2 Handshake message multiple times?

Tags: python, c, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

For example, in Python you create a socket, wrap it in TLS, and connect to a server. It automatically does the TLS in the background. What I want to do is to create a program (preferably in Python, I also know C) which **only sends the TLS1.2 ClientHello message multiple times**, not waiting for the Server to respond. (So I don't care about the Record Layer, it's only about the Handshake protocol, if it works I would later also try to send ChangeCipherSpec message for which I need to do proper KeyExchange.)

There are 2 possibilities I can think of:

1. **Change the OpenSSL library**. (I was looking how Python does the SSL, it uses the OpenSSL C library, but I think it would be hard to change all that to get what I want and to understand it. And it would be probs better to use C rather than Python for this case.)
2. Use a **Proxy** to drop the messages I don't want. (I haven't researched this that much, but it probably would be the easiest one to implement. I'm just not sure how I could do this)

Any tips on this would be appreciated. This is for a college project.

Comment: *...So I don't care about the Record Layer...* Everything in TLS is sent in a TLS record, including handshake messages like ClientHello. So you do care about the record layer. I'm not aware of any python APIs that let you specify TLS proceedings at that level of granularity. I can think of some hacky ways to do though it using the [SSLObject of the `ssl` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLObject) to capture a client hello and then send it to the peer, and then close the connection.

Comment: Why do you think you need to send it multiple times? It should get there the first time, and if it doesn't the others won't get there either. Please clarify.

Comment: @user207421 to see how the server reacts. Like Slow Dos Slowloris but for TLS, sending multiple Client Hello messages to see how much it would impact the server.

Comment: The ClientHello message is [well defined in the standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2), so just create it by your own without using any library. This is fairly easy and no complex cryptography involved here, the complexity comes only later in the TLS handshake. Apart from that you might use the [BIO](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/bio.html) functionality in OpenSSL in order to not write directly to a socket but to a memory buffer and then just stop after you've got the first message their.

Comment: OK well I can tell you how it reacts now. If it's a conforming TLS implementation it should send an alert 'unexpected message' and close the connection.

Comment: @user207421 I would send one ClientHello over each TCP connection I establish with the Server, I would not send multiple Hello messages over the same TCP connection...